# How to convert IST to CET timezone in c#,

Tags: c#, datetime-format

this did not work for me, "Central European Time" is not identified.

```cs
DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(values[1]);
TimeZoneInfo CET = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Time");
d = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(d,CET);
values[1] = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm}", d);
```

Comment: it should be `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(d,IST, CET);`

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code to your code.

```
TimeZoneInfo IST TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
d = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(d, IST);
```